# After light baking room environment looking poor - Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have just switched platform from Desktop to Android within Unity. 
In desktop platform environment looking proper after light baking.

But in Android everything looking poor after baking process get completed.
I have kept all lights of room as Mixed and made room environment to Static.

[image]

Now what to do for making environment look clear? I have done nothing special after switching platform in Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I can able to solve this problem myself. Posting here so that other users can make this point directly correct.

I forgot to enable **Generate Lightmap UVs** for imported models and without that try to do light baking process.

After this correction, scene light get baked properly. Following image for more clearance:

[image]